# How to obtain Fourier transform of a random list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, fft

I have solved a wave equation using numerical integration and stored the value of the wave function at each step in a python list. So what I have is a couple of lists:

`x=[1,1.001,1.002,.....4]` and

`psi= [1.571,1.579.....1]`

`x` is a list containing spatial coordinates and `psi` is a list with the corresponding values of my wave function. The `psi` vs `x` plot resembles a chirp signal([here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pp7sW.png)) and I'm interesting in extracting the frequencies present in it. It really seemed like a simple enough problem but I've browsed through the `np.fft` documentation and all the relevant questions on this community but I couldn't find what I was looking for.

**So my question is**: Given a waveform in space, how do I apply the Fourier transform to it to get the frequencies it contains?

**Edit:** I have written the following code:

```
fourier=np.fft.fft(p)   #p is a list
freq=np.fft.fftfreq(len(p),h)     #h is the step size of my grid
plt.xlabel('w')
plt.ylabel('Power')
plt.title("Fourier Transform")
plt.plot(freq,abs(fourier)**2)
```

And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV1Mx.png) is the result I got. But the problem is that there is only one peak, which I think corresponds to the average of the constituent frequencies. Is there any way to obtain the individual frequencies on python? Perhaps by using some other module such as `pywt`(wavelet transform)?

Comment: In general, it's as easy as this example shows: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html — use `np.fft.fft` (or similar) for the coefficients, and `np.fft.fftfreq` for the frequency (or wavenumber, in your case) values.

Comment: @kwinkunks  Thanks for the comment. So should I take the time step to be equal to the (spatial) step size in my integration?

Comment: Yes, exactly; as Prune says, there's nothing special about FFTs in time — they can be applied to any domain in principle.

Comment: @kwinkunks     I have implemented the code word to word, and the result I have is a peak of the at a frequency of around 1.333. However, just visually inspecting, there seem to be multiple sinusoidal waves with varying time periods(0.76, 0.8 ,0.5 etc.) in my original waveform. I believe that the result that I got is the average of all these frequencies. Is this a consequence of the fft module in numpy? Is there any way to obtain the finer frequencies individually?

Comment: The only way to get better frequency resolution is to pass a longer sequence of data. More samples means better resolution.

Comment: @kwinkunks     I have reduced my step size by a hundred times but there is till no change in the output at all. Is there any other way apart from this? Or should I just try getting it done with the wavelet transform?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. You have to pass a greater length (or time or whatever) of data. You can't just change the step size. So for example of I had 3 seconds of seismic data sampled every 2 ms, then to double the frequency resolution I need 6 s of data.  (To double the *bandwidth*, I need 1 ms samples.)

Comment: @kwinkunks     But for a given range, decreasing the step size increases the number of samples provided doesn't it? I can't increase the range because my data is fixed and cannot be extended beyond what has been given

Comment: It's not about the number of samples; the resolution in wavenumber is determined by the total range. If you only have a limited range of data, you can pad it with zeros... this will give more wavenumber samples but doesn't increase the bandwidth of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you showed in your plot, `x` is your equivalent to the time component.  Fourier analysis is not limited to time series; that's merely the most common application of his decomposition of general functions.